# Перевод слов для обращения к api

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, api, перевод

Всем вечер добрый, делаю приложение с погодой, подрубился к api openweathermap, но там города на английской, вопрос в том, как при вводе название города на русском, перевести его на английский, и отдать его api. Идей нет, кроме загрузки коллекции из названий городов на русском и на английском.

Comment: чем загрузка названий городов не устраивает?

Comment: А попробовать ввести это на русском, не? Вон я даже не поленился, сделал акк, получил ключ, подождал его активации и сделал запрос `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Москва&appid=[key]` и [получил успешно](https://pastebin.com/XQmLjXU3) результат по городу `Moscow`. Так что, лично я голосую за закрытие вопроса, ибо "не воспроизводится".

Comment: Из доков 'City name, state code and country code divided by comma, use ISO 3166 country codes.
You can specify the parameter **not only in English**. In this case, the API response should be returned in the same language as the language of requested location name'